# Keras/Tensorflow batch matrix multiplication across axis

Tags: tensorflow, matrix, keras, deep-learning

Say I have tensors

```
a
Out[15]: <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_2:0' shape=(?, 1152, 8) dtype=float32>
b
Out[16]: <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(16, 8, 1152, 10) dtype=float32_ref>
```

a represents a batch of 1152 8-dimensional vectors and 
b is 1152*10, (16, 8) matrices.

I wish to multiply those matrices with the 8-dimensional vectors in a and get a tensor of shape (None, 16, 1152, 10) back. I know in tensorflow one can use `einsum` to get this job done

`tf.einsum('ijkl,bkj->bikl', b, a)`

gives me the correct output and the shape. But `tf.einsum` is very slow compare to similar functions like `K.batch_dot` or `tf.tensordot`. However, I struggled to understand how these functions handle axes and broadcasting rules. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `transpose` and `reshape` you can achieve the same:

```
a : [batch, 1152, 8] --> reshape --> [batch, 1, 1, 1152, 8]
b : [16,8,1152,10]   --> transpose --> [16, 10, 1152, 8] 
                     --> expand_dims --> [1, 16, 10, 1152, 8]
multiply (a, b)      --> [batch, 16, 10, 1152, 8] 
reduce_sum axis 4    --> [batch, 16, 10, 1152]
```

Code:

```
#inputs
import numpy.testing as npt
x = np.random.normal(size=(5,1152,8)) 
y = np.random.normal(size=(16, 8, 1152, 10))

a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None, 1152, 8))
b = tf.constant(y, tf.float32)

out = tf.reduce_sum(tf.expand_dims(tf.transpose(b,[0, 3, 2, 1]),0) 
                   * tf.reshape(a,[-1,1,1,tf.shape(a)[1], tf.shape(a)[2]]), axis=4)
out = tf.transpose(out, [0,1,3,2])
out_ein = tf.einsum('ijkl,bkj->bikl', b, a)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    o = sess.run(out, {a: x})
    e = sess.run(out_ein, {a: x})
    npt.assert_almost_equal(o, e, decimal=5)
    #almost the same
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is it true that one would always have to match the rank of the tensors in order to undergo such operations? Also is it possible to replace multiply -> reduce_sum with batch dot?

Comment: For broadcasting, you need to have two dimensions equal, or 1. We cant use batch dot , because we not doing matrix multiplication here.